# How to create a QQ plot compared to a function I define?

Tags: r, qq-plot

I want to create a QQ plot with my sample data compared to the PDF $e^{-y}$. My $y > 0$.

My first approach was to create a random vector of values > 0, then plug those into $e^{-y}$ to get the realizations of $e^{-y}$, and plot the data against this.

I have been using the following R code:

```
values<- runif(length(dat$Cost), min = 0, max = 10)
RV <- c(exp(-values))
qqplot(dat$Cost, RV)
```

However, changing the max value greatly changes the shape of this QQ plot. I guess I could find the CDF of this function, and then find the range of $Y$ that most values fall into, but that still seems inefficient. Is there a R function that will create random values from a PDF I specify?

Comment: I ended up finding the CDF, then using a for() loop to calculate the y value for each quantile from .01 to 1. Then plotted my data against this vector. I guess this isn't the cleanest way, but maybe it works.

Comment: Reopened. While it contains code (and even asks for code) this is a question that requires a statistical answer. It even got one! (Close voters: Please see the [help/on-topic] on programming. It's pretty clear IMO. Even if you were in doubt over the question, reading the answer would have made it clear that it falls on our side of the line.)

Comment: Always a good idea to tell people the software you're using. Any tacit (worse expliicit) assumption that everyone uses X,. whatever X is, is a little irritating to the other people who don't.

Answer (score 3):

The QQ-plot (short for quantile-quantile plot) is a scatter plot showing the sample quantiles of a set of data against the theoretical quantiles of a proposed distribution.  The latter are  obtained from the [quantile function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function) of the distribution, which is the function-inverse of its CDF.  In your case, you are using the proposed distribution $Y \sim \text{Exp}(1)$ which has quantile function:

$$Q(p) = -\ln(1-p) \quad \quad \text{for all } 0 < p < 1.$$

Suppose your (increasing) ordered observed data is $y_{(1)} \leqslant ... \leqslant y_{(n)}$ and you want to construct a QQ-plot against your chosen distribution.  Then taking the sample quantile for $y_{(i)}$ to be $p_{(i)} \equiv \tfrac{2i-1}{2n}$ your QQ-plot should plot the data pairs $( -\ln(1-p_{(i)}), y_{(i)} )$.

In your question you are trying to get a QQ-plot by simulating values from the proposed distribution, but since this is a simple distribution, you can just get the theoretical quantiles analytically using the above form.  This will give you a basic QQ-plot for the proposed distribution.  There are variations on this version of the QQ-plot based on different formulae for the sample quantiles, but this is a basic one that will serve as a reasonable starting point.

---

**Example of a custom QQ plot:** Here is some `R` code to generate a custom QQ plot from scratch, without the use of a package.  The generated plot is shown below the code.  The sample data is generated from the theoretical distribution $Y_i \sim \text{IID Exp}(1)$ for $i=1,...,40$.

```
#Generate data from Exp(1) distribution
set.seed(123);
DATA <- rexp(40,1);


#QQ plot of data against Exp(1) distribution
N         <- length(DATA);
PERCS     <- ((1:N)-0.5)/N;
QUANTILES <- -log(1-PERCS);
PLOTDATA <- data.frame(Sample = sort(DATA),
                       Theoretical = QUANTILES);


#Generate custom QQ plot
library(ggplot2);
theme_update(plot.title    = element_text(size = 15, hjust = 0.5),
             plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 10, hjust = 0.5),
             axis.title.x  = element_text(size = 10, hjust = 0.5),
             axis.title.y  = element_text(size = 10, vjust = 0.5),
             plot.margin   = unit(c(1, 1, 1, 1), "cm"));

QQPLOT <- ggplot(data = PLOTDATA, aes(x = Theoretical, y = Sample)) +
          geom_point(size = 2, colour = 'blue') + 
          geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1, linetype = 'dashed') + 
          ggtitle('Quantile-Quantile Plot') + 
          labs(subtitle = '(Comparison to exponential distribution with unit scale)') + 
          xlab('Theoretical Quantiles') + 
          ylab('Sample Quantiles');

QQPLOT;
```

[image]

Comment: For a Stata-linked tutorial article with broadly similar flavour and several references  that could still be of some use or interest to people who don't use Stata see 2007. Quantile–quantile plots without programming. _Stata Journal_ 7: 275-279 https://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=gr0027 For more on "plotting positions" and alternatives to $(i - 0.5)/n$ see https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/percentile-ranks-and-plotting-positions/