# calculate quantile for exponential distribution

Tags: distributions, quantiles, exponential-distribution

My distribution function is: y=a * exp(-b*x)
What is the right way to calculate first Quartile?

Right now I do like that:

Q1=ln(4/3)/b

Is that correct?

Comment: Thank you.  Could you show us how you did the calculation and clarify where you need help?  We don't deal well with yes/no or multiple choice questions here: please see our [help] for further information.

Comment: You see, I have exponential distribution, and the question is that way (Q1=ln(4/3)/b) of calculating  Q1 correct or not

Comment: @Liz Hi, is this the classical exponential distribution, where the support is $x\geq 0$? If not, I could elaborate the solution for the general case.

Comment: I think [this answer to a related question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/350533/how-to-create-a-qq-plot-compared-to-a-function-i-define/350545#350545) answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

In general, distribution function refers to [CDF](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Cumulative_distribution_function), not PDF, i.e. density. So, your $y$ is a density. And, for exponential distribution, we need $a=b$, as well as the support is $x\geq 0$. Integrating yields the CDF as $$F_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^xf(x')dx'=\int_{0}^{x}{a \exp(-ax')dx'=-\exp(-ax')\big\rvert_{0}^{x}}=1-\exp(-ax)$$

$Q_1$ is the number where this CDF equals to $\frac{1}{4}$, i.e. $1-\exp(-ax)=\frac{1}{4}\rightarrow Q_1=\frac{1}{a}\log\frac{4}{3}$. Since $a=b$, your answer is correct.

If $a\neq b$ in general, and support $x\geq x_0$ (which can be expressed by $a$ and $b$), it won't be the classical exponential distribution we know, but the answer will be similar: $\frac{1}{b}\log\frac{4a}{3b}$, which reduces to your answer if $a=b$.

Comment: This is correct--but perhaps limited by the implicit assumption that the distribution is supported on the positive numbers.  The occurrence of both "$a$" and "$b$" in the formula suggests otherwise.  Because the formula "$a\exp(-bx)$" is thereby ambiguous, you might consider inquiring of the OP what the intended support is.

Comment: Yep, I've added the answer for the general case and asked for clarification.